# hadoop map reduce job fails : ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Error Launching job : Not a file:

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, streaming

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xla1j.jpg)[please check this link for the image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaBVo.jpg)

can not run the streaming job. mapper and reducer run in the local file system. but can not run using streaming job in hdfs

Comment: Did you get the solution ? I have the same issue.